# ZMQ Router Socket NOBLOCK

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a ZMQ Router socket to which several dealers connect and undergo a somewhat complicated set of transactions.  The final stages of the transaction require the dealer to make a send_multipart() call along the lines of:

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
skt = ctx.Socket(zmq.Router)
...
skt.send_multipart((b"workerID", b"", b"confirmation"))
```

This send happens in the main thread of the application, so I want to understand the behavior of this call.  In the case I do not specify the blocking behavior, it will send the message if possible, but according to the [ZMQ_ROUTER socket docs](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket), drop the message if either:

- The worker is no longer connected
- The high-water mark for the client (worker) is reached.

So here are my two questions:

- Is there any way in which specifying "flags=zmq.NOBLOCK" on this call changes its semantics?
- Is there any reason that this call would block even though I am not explicitly specifying zmq.NOBLOCK in the flags?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't specify no block it will block if high watermark is reached. If worker is no longer connected it will not block in both scenarios.

Comment: The documentation linked in the ZMQ_ROUTER section specifies that the router socket will drop when HWM is reached.  Hence my question as to whether the NOBLOCK option will ever change the semantics of the router socket.

Comment: So the docs are little off, it will block if NOBLOCK was not specified. I will update the docs.

Comment: Cool.  Not crazy.  Thank you!